# Error with third-party package: "Updating failed. Error message: The response is not a valid JSON response."

Tags: plugins

I'm new to WordPress and I obtained a package from a third party in `.zip` format. When I upload it on my Wordpress system, I see

> The package could not be installed. No valid plugins were found.

I reinstalled Wordpress from scratch (bitnami and AWS), and I still get the same error.

[This page](https://passionwp.com/response-is-not-a-valid-json-response-error/) suggests that it is a problem with SSL, so I have checked that and it all seems in order.

How can I fix it?

Comment: You should probably talk to Yootheme directly. If you can you should try and work out what URL their code is trying to call, e.g. by finding it in their code and tracing the URL out to error_log(), and then try that URL yourself both from another environment such as your desktop and from a shell on the server itself e.g. using curl - that way you'll be able to narrow down if the problem is at your end or theirs.

Comment: But - if you're confident it's not an SSL problem - without either the code or access to their server I'm not sure we can help you.

Comment: Rup is right, you need to contact the vendor for support, 3rd party theme/plugin support is offtopic here

Comment: OK for 3rd-party support as off-topic. The answer may be on-topic and useful for others: I was trying to install a theme as a plugin. Something clicked when I saw the error message for the third time, "no valid plugin", and the name of the vendor, "yootheme". In addition to being new to third-party vendor yootheme, I'm also new to Wordpress. I'm happy to edit the question to be more generic and post an answer if you decide that it's on topic.

Comment: You've solved this? Great. If it isn't something specific to Yootheme then yes, click the 'flag' link and ask for it to be reopened. I'm not sure how a plugin would fix a "not a valid JSON response" error though?

Comment: You're just uploading a zipped plugin? Where do you get the "not a valid JSON response" error?

Comment: @Rup Yes, I solved this and flagged for reopening. I was uploading a zipped theme and I got that response after uploading it as a plugin.